# Programmatically implement TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview

I have try to implement TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView programmatically, but i did not get the correct result..

```
TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView *keyboardAvoidingScrollView = [[TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
```

And add some UItextFields in keyboardAvoidingScrollView
Finally added keyboardAvoidingScrollView in [self.view addSubview:keyboardAvoidingScrollView];

The TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView is added in the self.view - but the TextField are not added inside the keyboardAvoidingScrollView

Kindly help me..

Thanks in advance..